# Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am using windows 10 task scheduler to run tasks that require me using my personal user account (its necessary to use my user and not system user because of permission issues - I am part of an organization).
In windows 7 computers everything worked fine but as we upgraded to win 10 I cant run the tasks without using the System user (as mentioned before it doesn't work because of permissions).
I get the following error

**Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726**

all I found online was an advice to use the system user other then that nothing :-(

please save my day.

here is a picture of the settings that I want to change.

[image: img of the task scheduler]

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Today I got the same problem,  (HRESULT) 0x8007052e (2147943726) "unknown user name or bad password"

**My solution:** was to Re-Asign the User on the "Change User or Group" button to get the lattest Active Directory information of the User.

Then I could Run the Task Again...

> As a better practice, you could use an "Aplicative" User instead of a
>   regular User which change more often in regular basis.
>
> If you use your account, it may change your password every some
>   quantity of days... and you will need to "fix it" again...
>
> If you use an "Aplicative" account, it may change less than regular
>   User...
>
> You could do this by going to the task tab "General", 
>   then "Change User or Group" and assigning the "Aplicative" account,
>   then "OK" Button.

Comment: According to https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-task-scheduler-error-value-2147943726/, the applicative object name is "Users".

Comment: With "Users" (BUILTIN\Users), the task was running in the foreground.
So i used "System" (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM).

Comment: I think,..... the second Method 2 in the url appuals.com... is working changing to stop the instance, but the correction is about getting again the password to change the task, not about setting to stop the instance.... because the problem it is not having the password... so when you enter and change anything not important, but write down again the password, then it is actualiced the password itself and it is solved because of that... not the stop... Regards from México!!!

Answer (score 42):

I had the same issue with the windows task scheduler.

The reason for the failure is the recent change in the password of the system user which was configured at the time of task creation.

**Solution:**

- Go to properties of task
- Under General tab, click on "Change User or Group..."
- Enter the username in the field "Enter the object name to select"
- This will ask for Authentication, provide your credentials

Thats it !

Comment: If this is a first-time setup as in my case, in a corporate tech development context, the key details i miss was use my corporate username at the step: enter the username in the field "Enter the object name to select". After using my corporate username and password, I was able to run a batch script to start my Citrix desktop at pre-determned time.

Comment: As a security measure, my password is automatically replaced every day by our IT department. Is there an alternative solution for scheduling an automated task when the password is not constant?

Comment: Late, but worth noting that some IT departments will set up 'service accounts' for automation and exclude it from password policies that would prevent automated tasks from running.

Answer (score 13):

I had to select the option to "Do not store password.   The task will only have access to local computer resources.", which was fine based on what the task was defined as.   For me, I suspect some sort of recent patch or security hardening caused this as it seemed to move through our environments at similar but different days.

Answer (score 9):

I know it is a late answer, I had the same issue today, a scheduled task I had created a long time ago and stopped running a week ago. Turns out I had changed the password for my username which was the issue. once I went back to the task, made a change I was asked for the password again.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, and found this other link with screen shots, which was very helpful: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-task-scheduler-error-value-2147943726/

Answer (score 5):

After reading this post this is what worked for me.
Go to properties of task
Under General tab, at the bottom of that window you will see
Configure for: Change that to the system you are using
(in my case server 2012 R2) hit ok and enter your password.

Answer (score 4):

When choosing "Run whether user is logged in or not" on Windows Server 2019 I was getting the error message:

> An error has occurred for task Dealer Portal data import. Error message: The following error was reported: 2147943712

There is a Group Policy setting that stops this working, you can disable it with the following steps:

1. Start > Run > secpol.msc
2. Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication
3. Disable that

Now you can save the Scheduled Task

Comment: This was our problem. We made a Group Policy change that included the "Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication" setting set to "Enabled" that was causing a couple scheduled tasks to fail with error code 2147943712.


Our solution was to set the task to "Only run when user is logged on" since we would like to keep this policy in place. This works since the VM the tasks run from is dedicated to this single user and it stays signed in.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Control Panel>System and Security>Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a batch job

Add the System User.

Answer (score 3):

What I realized is that failure is tied to a password expired policy. The PC got a sort of "frozen" state for the scheduler until a new password is set. The problem is solved once the new password is taken into account by the system.

Highly recommended to perform a little change for the scheduler to ask a new password entry and update the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply edit the properties of each task (you don't have to change anything), hit ok, and you'll be prompted for your new password. "Conveniently", I didn't see a way to do all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with Windows 2012 server machines being cloned on a vmware ESX server. The clone/deployment script used sysprep to make every machine individual. With this the users assigned with the scheduled task got screwed up. Our solution was to re-generate the task via batchfile during startup of the machine:

```
REM Delete the task:
SCHTASKS /Delete /TN "NameOfScheduledTask" /f

REM Create a task to run every 5 minutes
SCHTASKS /Create /TN NameOfScheduledTask /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /TR "some command for task" /NP
```