# Task Scheduler will run a PS1 script if it is the first Action but not if it is the second action

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a task scheduled on a Windows 10 computer to run our billing at night.  The billing program creates a log file.  The file is definitely closed at the end of the billing program.  The second action of the task is to use Powershell to email the log to the relevant people. The action is set up as follows:

```
Start a Program: Powershell.exe
```

The arguments added are:

```
-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Program Files (x86)\AIM Tasks\EmailNightlyBilling.ps1"
```

EmailNightlyBilling is as follows:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$file = "C:\Program Files (x86)\AIM Tasks\MPSBillingLog.txt"

$smtpServer = "192.168.1.X"

$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = "administrator@domain.com"

$msg.To.Add("user@domain.com")

$msg.Subject = "Nightly Billing Results"

$msg.Body = "Nightly Billing run on old dev computer."

$msg.Attachments.Add($att)

$smtp.Send($msg)

$att.Dispose()

exit
```

If I create the action in a task where it is the first action, then it runs fine and emails the log file.  If I create the action as the second action of the task, I get

```
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Nightly Billing" task for user "Domain\Administrator". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
```

I have this same setup on a Windows Server 2012 and it works fine as the second action.  I have no clue why Windows 10 would be any different.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348330/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data-error-value-2147943726

Comment: I have set the creds several times.  It's not that that it won't run, it's that it won't run unless it is the first Action of the Task.