# PowerShell Task Scheduler job failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944187

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Registered a PowerShell Scheduled job using the following script:

```
enter $T = New-JobTrigger -Daily -AT "04:00 AM" here
enter Register-ScheduledJob -Name JobName -FilePath C:\Jobs\myScript.ps1 -Trigger $T here
```

When I try to Run this job using Windows Task Scheduler I get the following issue:

**Task Scheduler failed to start "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\JobName" task for user "myUser". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147944187.**

There is a pretty the same issue [Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348330/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data-error-value-2147943726) but with different Error Value ID. Anyway, I tried all suggestions from there but no results.

Some more details:

- Current user is not an Administator
- I've check the box Run with highest privileges
- Machine - Windows Server 2012

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your user `myUser` has the `logon as a batch job` privilege on the respective computer?

Comment: I guess this could help with your issue https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/143dea90-8e16-407d-946f-87f7ba939f42/scheduled-task-fails-with-error-code-0x800706fb?forum=winservergen

Comment: @TobyU, yes the `myUSer` has the logon as a batch job privilege.

Comment: @montonero probably that could be helpful, thanks. will check.